# I'm using a backup utility to backup my linux to an SMB share..having case sensitivity issues

Tags: linux, backup, server-message-block, share

I'm mounting an SMB share with an ext3 formatted drive from my home router. 
Wanting to backup some information from my linux box to the share. Is SMB/CIFS shared. Having issues with the fact that TEST==test in the eyes of the SMB so it is failing the backup. 
Wondering how I can make TEST!=test in the eyes of the share to oget things running  OK.

I have added

```
case sensitive = yes
```

to the globals section of my smb.conf file and

when I

```
 touch test.txt
```

it creates the file but when I then

```
touch TEST.txt
```

nothing happens.....

Thanks
-R

Comment: @Lenniey I read that but really didn’t understand it

Comment: @Lenniey please see above answer editded